# linux + file printed with the linux prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cat, vi

when we print the file- /etc/hosts.txt
we get after the last line the - [root@master02 data]# , why?

we try dos2linux , and by vi we not see any charterer after the last line - worker03.yu.com 14.23.45.66

```
[root@master02 data]# cat /etc/hosts.txt
master01.yu.com 14.23.45.61
master02.yu.com 14.23.45.62
master03.yu.com 14.23.45.63
worker01.yu.com 14.23.45.64
worker02.yu.com 14.23.45.65
worker03.yu.com 14.23.45.66[root@master02 data]#
```

expected output

```
cat /etc/hosts.txt
master01.yu.com 14.23.45.61
master02.yu.com 14.23.45.62
master03.yu.com 14.23.45.63
worker01.yu.com 14.23.45.64
worker02.yu.com 14.23.45.65
worker03.yu.com 14.23.45.66
[root@master02 data]#
```

Comment: you can view the _end of line_ with `cat -e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file doesn’t end with a new line; it’s harmless, but if you want to fix it, run

```
echo >> /etc/hosts.txt
```

Comment: but we not want space on the last line

Comment: Did you try it? You won’t get a space on the last line.

Comment: I test it and it create space on the last line

Comment: How did you determine that there was a space on the last line?

Comment: echo >> $file   , and then by vi I see space on the last line , also with wc -l

Comment: you can try it just do echo >>/tmp/test ; echo >>/tmp/test  , you will see two spaces

Comment: Yes, that’s similar to what I’d done, but in my case I just get a one-byte file, containing the new line only.

Comment: Does `od -a -t x1 /etc/hosts.txt` end with a space (`20` in the hex output)?

Comment: its ended with 0000360

Comment: That’s the offset, not the contents. The contents are on the right-hand side.

Comment: I only want the file ended with new line but new line must be empty

Comment: Yes, and that’s what the above does. You’ll get a file that ends with `0a` in `od`’s output; that’s a new line, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to achieve the same

---

```
sed '$s/$/\n/g' /etc/hosts
```

---